# Не могу динамично изменить файл з параметрами загрузки

Tags: java

Очень нужна помощь.В Java не долго, так что костылей полно, прошу сильно не пинать).
Есть клас Level1State в котором я вызываю saveProp() чтоб занести параметры в файл  и lastLoad() чтобы получить параметры

```
public static GameProps p = new GameProps();
//saveProp 
public void saveProp(){
p.save(getHero(), hero.getHealth(), getXposition(), getYposition(),getState(),tileMap.getx(), tileMap.gety());
}
//lastLoad
public void lastLoad()
{
p.load();
tileMap.setPosition((double) p.loadInt().get(3), (double) p.loadInt().get(4));
}
```

Здесь собственно сам клас который все делает

```
public class GameProps {

String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
final String settingsFilename = homeDir + File.separator + "mySettings.txt";
final Properties props = new Properties();
String hero_type;
int hero_health;
int hero_position_x;
int hero_position_y;
String game_state;
double tilemap_position_x;
double tilemap_position_y;

 public List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
public List<Integer> linesInt = new ArrayList<>();

FileOutputStream output;

 public void save(String hero_type, int hero_health, int hero_position_x, int hero_position_y,
        String game_state, double tilemap_position_x, double tilemap_position_y) {
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(settingsFilename);

    } catch (Exception ignore) {

    }

    try {
        props.setProperty("hero_type", hero_type);
        props.setProperty("hero_health", Integer.toString(hero_health));
        props.setProperty("hero_position_x", Integer.toString(hero_position_x));
        props.setProperty("hero_position_y", Integer.toString(hero_position_y));
        props.setProperty("game_state", game_state);
        props.setProperty("tilemap_position_x", Double.toString(tilemap_position_x));
        props.setProperty("tilemap_position_y", Double.toString(tilemap_position_y));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        this.hero_type = "Drago";
        this.hero_health = 2;
        this.hero_position_x = 10;
        this.hero_position_y = 10;
        this.game_state = "Level1State";
        this.tilemap_position_x = 0.0;
        this.tilemap_position_y = 0.0;
    }
    try {
        props.store(output, "Saved settings");
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }

}

public void load() {

    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(settingsFilename);
            props.load(input);

    } catch (Exception ignore) {

    }

    hero_health = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("hero_health", Integer.toString(hero_health)));
    hero_type = props.getProperty("hero_type", hero_type);
    hero_position_x = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("hero_position_x", Integer.toString(hero_position_x)));
    hero_position_y = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("hero_position_y", Integer.toString(hero_position_y)));
    game_state = props.getProperty("game_state", game_state);
    tilemap_position_x = Double.parseDouble(props.getProperty("tilemap_position_x", Double.toString(tilemap_position_x)));
    tilemap_position_y = Double.parseDouble(props.getProperty("tilemap_position_y", Double.toString(tilemap_position_y)));
    Collections.addAll(lines, hero_type, game_state);
    Collections.addAll(linesInt, hero_health, hero_position_x, hero_position_y,
            (int) tilemap_position_x, (int) tilemap_position_y);
    System.out.println(linesInt.get(0));


}

public List<Integer> loadInt() {
    return linesInt;
}

public List<String> loadString() {
    return lines;
}
}
```

Когда запускаю прогу, последние сохраненные параметры загружаются, все ок, но они сохраняются только когда прога завершает свою роботу,а когда хочу сохранить во время эксплуатации то не получается.

Comment: И в чем проблема вызвать метод saveProp в нужный момент?

Comment: я в нужный момент вызываю, но эффекта нет, изменения в файл не вносятся. Вносятся тогда когда уже  прога закрыта.

Comment: Как минимум, `FileOutputStream` нужно закрывать после работы, или использовать `lock-with-resources`

Comment: хорошее замечание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в том, что  в методе Save вы сначала сохраняете состояние props, потом меняете состояние props

```
public void save(String hero_type, int hero_health, int hero_position_x, int hero_position_y,
        String game_state, double tilemap_position_x, double tilemap_position_y) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(settingsFilename);
            props.store(output, "Saved settings"); // **вот тут вы сохраняете в файл** 

    } catch (Exception ignore) {

    }

   // **дальше меняйте  props** 
    try {
        props.setProperty("hero_type", hero_type);
        props.setProperty("hero_health", Integer.toString(hero_health));
        props.setProperty("hero_position_x", Integer.toString(hero_position_x));
        props.setProperty("hero_position_y", Integer.toString(hero_position_y));
        props.setProperty("game_state", game_state);
        props.setProperty("tilemap_position_x", Double.toString(tilemap_position_x));
        props.setProperty("tilemap_position_y", Double.toString(tilemap_position_y));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        this.hero_type = "Drago";
        this.hero_health = 2;
        this.hero_position_x = 10;
        this.hero_position_y = 10;
        this.game_state = "Level1State";
        this.tilemap_position_x = 0.0;
        this.tilemap_position_y = 0.0;
    }
 // метод завершается и последнее сохранение не пишем в файл.

}
```

Вам нужно кусок `props.store(output, "Saved settings");` выполнить в конце метода `save`

Comment: ошибок меньше, но без изменений = ( . Я вызываю метод saveProp() в нужный момент, завершаю роботу программы, включаю программу и только тогда изменения вступают в силу, а не сразу после вызова методов saveProp и lastLoad()

Comment: http://ideone.com/7Bo4m3 вот рабочий код. видимо из-за того, что не печатаешь ошибки exaption, ты не видишь какие ошибки возникают и почему. добавь в `catch` `ignore.printStackTrace(); `

Comment: Спасибо! Код нормально заработал. Наверное все дело в том, что надо было напрямую указывать параметры.

Comment: Нажмите кто-нибудь "Ответ полезен".

Comment: если мой ответ помог, то принимаешь как правильный. иначе добавь свой ответ. либо обнови мой ответ своим дополнением